# Query for status change first time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-modeling

I have a table like below

```
      CREATE TABLE Customers_History(Row_Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                             Cust_Name VARCHAR(255),
                             Created_Date DATE,
                             Cust_Status TINYINT)
```

The rows in the table are below

```
INSERT INTO Customers_History(Cust_Name, Created_Date, Cust_Status)
                     VALUES('Customer A', '20120516', 0),
                           ('Customer B', '20120516', 0),
                           ('Customer C', '20120516', 0),

                           ('Customer A', '20120517', 1),
                           ('Customer B', '20120517', 0),
                           ('Customer C', '20120517', 0),

                           ('Customer A', '20120520', 1),
                           ('Customer B', '20120520', 0),
                           ('Customer C', '20120520', 1),

                           ('Customer A', '20120521', 0),
                           ('Customer B', '20120521', 0),
                           ('Customer C', '20120521', 1),

                           ('Customer A', '20120526', 1),
                           ('Customer B', '20120526', 1),                
                           ('Customer C', '20120526', 0);
```

I want a Query which Brings Output as Below by taking date as parameter

When i pass 20120517 as parameter for date in where class it should bring Customer A as its status changes from 0 to 1

```
  Customer A
```

When i pass 20120520 as parameter for date in where class it should bring Customer C as its status changes from 0 to 1

```
  Customer C
```

When i pass 20120526 as parameter for date in where class it should bring Customer B as its status changes from 0 to 1

```
  Customer B
```

I want the Customers name for particular date whose status changed from 0 to 1 for the first time.

Note : When i pass 20120526 as parameter for date in where class it should not bring Customer A since Customer A Status Changed from 0 to 1 on 17 itself.

Comment: A table named 'Customers' I would expect to contain just unique customers, not a number of stated per customer. Rather create a separate table CustomerStates that contains this data and is linked to Customers with a CustomerID.

Comment: I am tracking customer history in this table.If i create a separate table as you said how do i track customer status in that

Comment: Then name it CustomerHistory. The current table suggests it is your customers table, containing actual customers.

Comment: Alright, modified my answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
select
  c.Cust_Name
from
  Customers_History c
where
  c.CreatedDate = :YourDate and
  c.Cust_Status = 1 and
  not exists 
    ( select 
        'x' 
      from 
        Customers_History c2
      where 
        c2.Cust_Name = c.CustName and
        c2.Cust_Status = 1 and
        c2.Created_Date < c.Created_Date )
```

Comment: Worked Like charm Thanks a ton. I hope you wont mind if I ask you the proper table design for the above requirement.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select Cust_Name from customers_history where Created_Date='2012-05-17' and 
Cust_Status=1 order by Cust_Name desc limit 1
```

Comment: You haven't understood my question